# How to run all permutations of a test set, break at first "fail" and keep results of last "pass" per permutation

Tags: r, testing, permutation

I have multiple tests to perform on my data. I have already built a function for each test separately. For example, here is a function of one test (which is not our concern, it runs well):

```
R <- function(series, alpha=0.05) {
  library(tseries)
  library(LSTS)
  model <- 0
  ######################### Random Walk test #########################
  #H0: iid residuals
  RW <- Box.test(series, lag=1, type="Ljung")
  p_value3 <- RW$p.value
  if (p_value3 > alpha) {print("Failt to reject H_0, No autocorrolation, this is a Random Walk process !")
    model <- 2 
  }
  return(model)
}
```

For summary, I have four functions each performing a test. The functions are "C","R","L" and "Y" each returning a score of 1,2,3 and 4 respectively.

I want to do a permutation of tests, but i don't know how can i do it for all the 24 combinations.

Perumtation 1: CLYR
Start with "C" test, if rejected go to "L" test, if rejected go to "Y" test, if rejected go to "R" test.

Note: once a test is accepted, we stop and we keep the score returned.
Note: if all tests are rejected, the score is 0

At the end of the 24 permutations, we count the frequency of scores. For example,

| Score | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about:

```
library(combinat) ## provides permutation function "permn"
```

- define your test list:

```
tests <- list(
  C = list(f = \(x) {x < 10},  score = 1),
  R = list(f = \(x) {x < 30},  score = 2),
  L = list(f = \(x) {x < 50},  score = 3),
  Y = list(f = \(x) {x < Inf}, score = 4)
)
```

- get the list of permutations:

```
perms <- combinat::permn(c('C', 'R', 'L', 'Y'))
```

```
## > perms
## [[1]]
## [1] "C" "R" "L" "Y"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "C" "R" "Y" "L"
## truncated
```

- iterate over the permutations, shuffling your test list according to each permutation, `do.call`ing the test functions in the shuffled orders, identifying the index of the latest passed (before first failed) test and retrieving the associated score:

```
perms |>
  Map(f = \(perm) {
    tests_shuffled <- tests[perm]
    latest_pass <- - 1 + which(tests_shuffled |> 
                              Map(f = \(test) do.call(test$f, list(x = 42))) == FALSE
                              )[1]
    score <- ifelse(latest_pass < 1, 0, tests_shuffled[[latest_pass]]$score)
    c(paste(perm, collapse = ''), score)
  }) |>
  Reduce(f = rbind) |>
  as.data.frame(row.names = FALSE) |>
  setNames(nm = c('perm', 'score'))
```

output:

```
   perm score
1  CRLY     0
2  CRYL     0
3  CYRL     0
4  YCRL     4
5  YCLR     4
6  CYLR     0
7  CLYR     0
8  CLRY     0
9  LCRY     3
## truncated
```

- to tabulate scores, store above output to object and `table` it, or simply append `|> (\(.) table(.$score))()` to the previous pipe:

```
## +   setNames(nm = c('perm', 'score')) |>
## +   (\(.) table(.$score))()
 0  3  4 
12  6  6
```

Comment: thank you a lot ! I will try it immediately!